# Pandas column filtering on string gives unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column `ClientAccount` which contains a lot of test data data which I want to filter out.

To find how many rows contains test clients, I do the following:

```
test_users = order_data[order_data['ClientAccount'].str.contains("DEMO|test")==True]
```

Which returns `Name: ClientAccount, Length: 2493`

Cool, so 2.493 rows out of 71.458 original rows.

Then to get get everything that isn't these 2.493 rows, shouldn't I just do the opposite?

```
order_data = order_data[order_data['ClientAccount'].str.contains("DEMO|test")==False]
```

This gives 48.046 rows though, but how does that make sense? What am I missing?

Comment: Is possible some NaN values?

Comment: Oh, that was it. `isnull().sum()` on the df returns 20.919..

Answer (score 1):

I think there are `NaN` or `None` values, so is possible use parameter `na` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Also for inversing boolean mask (`True` + `False` `Series`) use `~`:

```
mask = order_data['ClientAccount'].str.contains("DEMO|test", na=False)

test_users1 = order_data[mask]
test_users2 = order_data[~mask]
```

---

Sample:

```
order_data = pd.DataFrame({'ClientAccount':['DEMO ss','test f','dfd', None, np.nan, 'test']})
print (order_data)
  ClientAccount
0       DEMO ss
1        test f
2           dfd
3          None
4           NaN
5          test

mask = order_data['ClientAccount'].str.contains("DEMO|test", na=False)

test_users1 = order_data[mask]
test_users2 = order_data[~mask]

print (test_users1)
  ClientAccount
0       DEMO ss
1        test f
5          test

print (test_users2)
  ClientAccount
2           dfd
3          None
4           NaN
```

Without parameter I get error:

```
mask = order_data['ClientAccount'].str.contains("DEMO|test")
```

> ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values